# Inline CSS with Styled Components

Tags: styled-components, preact

I have used styled components for my Preact project, it was work fine if I have index.html where styled's random CSS classes are injected.

I want to inject inline CSS instead of injecting CSS classes to my template html.

Comment: What do you want to use this for? Emails?

Comment: For library where we will have JS file only, don't have CSS or HTML files

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> If you are a library author, we recommend that you should not bundle and ship styled-components module with your library. There are two steps that you need to do to achieve this:
>
> Marking styled-components as external in your package dependencies
> Removing styled-components from your library bundle

This is because `styled-components` package is supposed to be used a singleton. Only one version of the library is supposed to exist in a project (just like `react` or `react-dom`).

To do this in your library, you have to move `styled-components` as a dependency to `devDependencies` or `peerDependencies`. [Docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#marking-styledcomponents-as-external-in-your-package-dependencies).

As long as there is a HTML file where your library will be used (and the user install styled-components), the library will work fine.